# black screen and error 400 bad request

Tags: telnet, apache

I was trying telnet into a Web server and send a multiline request message. I have to include in the request message the `If-modified-since`. I made settings for Win7.

For instance when I type `telnet edition.cnn.com 80` on my command prompt, it opens a black empty screen, I don't see any thing that I type.

Then I wrote this line on the black screen `GET pageName HTTP/1.0`, it returned `400 Bad Request Error` and says connection closed. What should I do? I  used get pagename for an example.

Comment: The Windows telnet client is notoriously bad. Try again with something like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Comment: ok I finally get the content by typing just for a page GET /21838937.asp now I have to include If-modified-since

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use e.g. a telnet client to manually get web-pages, you have to remember the format of a HTTP request header:

```
GET pageName HTTP/1.0
additional header
additional header
```

Note that the last line is an empty line. You might also need `HTTP/1.1` for certain headers to make sense. Please read a HTTP specification for more information and what headers are standard.

---

The "black  screen" is simply the telnet program running in a command window.

Comment: and what about the blank screen op is mentioning ?

Comment: Also, case matters. If you write `http/1.1` you _will_ get a `400 Bad Request` response and bang your head against the wall not knowing what went wrong. Ask me how I know.

Answer (score 2):

400 is an HTTP error code, meaning you did succesfully send a message to the server, it was just invalid HTTP (probably a simple typo)
The black screen and not seeing what you type is 'normal' behavior for telnet (at least I always had that).

If you use a tool like Putty you can see what you type, so it becomes easier to do this sort of thing, and spot your typo.
See the tutorial here: http://www.hellboundhackers.org/articles/571-spoofing-http-requests-with-putty.html

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to anything other than basic interaction with the web server I'd suggesting using a tool specifically made for the job, for example [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). It will allow you set headers etc.

```
curl -H "If-Modified-Since:04-Nov-2012 11:59:00 GMT" http://host.com/21838937.asp
```